# How to display custom error message in spring mvc 4 by not using web.xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

i am new to spring mvc and am trying to display custom error message using @ResponseStatus annotation and am not able to achieve the required output.

How do i fix it?

Should i be using json to fix this?

Do i need to make any changes in web.xml?

**Controller class**

```
 @Controller
    public class IndexController {
        @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
        @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,reason = "My Response Status Change....!!")
        public String handleResourceNotFoundException() {
            return "notfound";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/index")
        public String indexController(Model model){
            return "index";
        }
    }
```

---

**ResourceNotFoundException class**

```
package com.news.errorHandlers;

    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;

    @ControllerAdvice
    public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException{

    }
```

---

**notFound.jsp**

```
<h1 class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">${value}</h1>
```

Comment: it's not clear what are you trying to achieve here but if you are working with the InternalResourceViewResolver you should make sure that you return "notFound" and not "notfound" jsp names are case sensitive. do you expect the ${value} to be the @ResponseStatus reason ? this will not work .

Comment: i am using Apache tiles view-resolver and i want to display error 404 error for page not found exception and how do i achieve other than declaring error code in web.xml.